# Spring's Cacheable not working - Not returning results from Cache

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm trying to use Spring @Cacheable on a Method but its Not Working.

```
 import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;

public class CacheableService {


    @Cacheable(value = "entityCount")
    public int someEntityCount(final String criteria) {
        System.out.println("Inside function : " + criteria);
        return 5;
    } }
```

**Beans Initialization :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<cache:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean name = "impactLevelsCache" class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean">
                <property name="name" value="impactLevels" />
            </bean>
            <bean name = "entityCountBean" class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean">
                <property name="name" value="entityCount" />
            </bean>
        </set>
</bean>


</beans>
```

I am not Getting what mistake I'm making. It always invoking the method. I have also enabled Trace Logs but its not logging anything specific to Caching.
Also tried calling it from test cases, but cache not working. (Invocation is from different class. There is no Self-Invocation).

```
import org.junit.Test; import org.junit.runner.RunWith; import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration; import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// Using same Bean configuration for Testing also.
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/com/amazon/pickuppointcapacity/test/appconfig2.xml")
public class RoughTest {


    @Test
    public void testSomeEntityCountCalledTwice_shouldCallDaoMethodOnce() {
        CacheableService cacheableService = new CacheableService();
        cacheableService.someEntityCount("A");
        cacheableService.someEntityCount("A");
        cacheableService.someEntityCount("A");
        cacheableService.someEntityCount("A");

    }
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried to add `@Service` to `CacheableService` and use `compant-scan` to autowire the service instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `CacheableService` in your test, which means it is not managed by Spring and non of the Spring annotations will work in it.

For spring to kick in, you need to get your service as a bean, autowired into your test class

Comment: Thanks Nir. Just a follow up question. In our service we are already initializing a Bean (say "A") and that internally constructing a "CacheableService" Object by using - new CacheableService(). And as you mentioned that we can't use spring caching over methods of class, initialized using "new" Keyword. Then whats an alternative or a way to cache method response ?

Comment: if bean A is creating the service using 'new' keyword - the cachable annotation will not work there, as the service will not be a spring bean. the alternative - the service should be created as a bean and autowired into all other beans that uses it

Comment: Thanks Nir. And if thats not possible due to hard-coupling/Big Service. Then we'll have to move to other caching solutions like Guava caching or something like that. Right ?

Comment: to me it sounds that the the hard-coupling is creating it with new, autowire is the loose coupling way in my mind, but to your question - if it's not a bean - it wont work

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot Nir.